# Schema.org - an Organization schema that references the parent organization schema (of another website)

Tags: schema, json-ld, structured-data

Our agency has a website where I implemented an Organization schema in the form of JSON-LD. I want to create an Organization schema for each of the websites we own, but also to add a reference (something similar to the isPartOf) to the Organization schema on our agency site.
What's the best practice?

I have the Organization schema ready (for the agency site and for each of the sites we own), but I am not sure how to reference the the agency within each site's individual Organization schema

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that all these `Organization` objects represent the same organization (instead of sub-organizations or similar):

- You could [use the same identifier (`@id`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75556552/19579546) for all of them, which conveys that the organizations *are* the same.
- You could give them the same [`schema:url`](https://schema.org/url) value, which conveys that the organizations have the same webpage URL.
- You could use [`schema:sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) to reference the primary page about the organization on its main site (e.g., the homepage if the whole website is only about that organization).

### Example

On the agency website:

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://agency.example.com/",
    "name": "Example",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "https://agency.example.com/#org",
        "url": "https://agency.example.com/",
        "name": "Example Agency",
        "description": "…"
    },
    "about": { "@id": "https://agency.example.com/#org" }
}
```

On an owned website, option 1 (repeating the data):

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://foo.example/",
    "name": "Foo",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "https://agency.example.com/#org",
        "url": "https://agency.example.com/",
        "sameAs": "https://agency.example.com/",
        "name": "Example Agency",
        "description": "…"
    }
}
```

On an owned website, option 2 (repeating only the data most essential for identification):

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://bar.example/",
    "name": "Bar",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "https://agency.example.com/#org",
        "url": "https://agency.example.com/",
        "sameAs": "https://agency.example.com/"
    }
}
```

On an owned website, option 3 (only referencing the identifier):

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "name": "Baz",
    "url": "https://baz.example/",
    "publisher": { "@id": "https://agency.example.com/#org" }
}
```

Option 3 would be fine for consumers which have all relevant data (i.e., the RDF from all of the agency’s websites) in their triplestore. This would most likely not be the case for consumers which do something with a specific page, e.g., displaying a rich result in their search results. For these consumers, you would have to repeat all necessary data for the rich result.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your poster, your organization has other organizations in its structure as children of the main organization. In this case, if the parent organization is a corporation or consortium, then you can use the appropriate type `Corporation` or the type `Consortium` for the parent organization. To mark up child organizations in the parent's content, you can use the property `subOrganization`. To markup the parent in the children's content, you can use the property `parentOrganization`.

If there are only departments, then you can use the property `department`.