# The puzzling semantics of rdf:type

Tags: rdf, ontology

Although I have created several ontologies and have some expertise, I have been unclear about the semantics of rdf:type for some time. The W3C spec says "`rdf:type is an instance of rdf:Property that is used to state that a resource is an instance of a class.`

In the following example, the subject `mus:12345` is not a vase object itself, but a page describing it.

```
@prefix voc: <http://somemuseum.com/ontology#> .
@prefix mus: <http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/> .
voc:Vase rdf:type owl:Class .
mus:12345 rdf:type voc:Vase .
```

It seems to me the semantics of these statements is:
"the web page `http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345` is an object defined by `http://somemuseum.com/ontology#Vase`"

But it is not the object, it is a web page. Isn't it more precise to say
`mus:12345 rdf:type voc:VaseDescription`, or `mus:12345 rdf:type voc:ArtifactDescription`?

In this example, the information I would want to convey is: "there is an object of the class Vase, described by the web page `http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345`. And then things like that Vase object is 25cm tall and so on. But does this statement convey that?
`mus:12345 voc:height "25cm"`? After all, `mus:12345` is a page not a vase.

Comment: "is not a vase object itself, but a page describing it": What makes you think that?

Comment: `mus:1234` is an alias for `http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345`, which is a pointer to a web page. The web page is not 25cm tall, the vase is. It is implicit that the page only describes the actual vase, not explicit.

Comment: Do you mean that you found an example in the wild where `http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345` is used for both, i.e., 1) for the webpage about the vase, and 2) for the subject in that RDF triple? Or what else makes you think that the URL is "a pointer to a web page"?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/. See also "HttpRange-14" mentioned there. Perhaps the web page address is `http://somemuseum.com/doc/12345` or something like.

Comment: `mus:12345` is the address of a web resource, not a vase. The statement `mus:12345 voc:height "25cm"`, taken literally says "the resource at this address has a height of 25cm." The interpretation "the object described by the doc at this address is 25cm tall" is implied. Web resources contain authored assertions. Another statement might be `musx:9876 voc:height "15cm"` with the object referenced by `mus:12345` & `musx:9876` being the same thing. In my actual case (places), there are many web resources making conflicting claims about the same place. So it's about provenance. Thx for discussing

Comment: @StanislavKralin Yes! This is exactly the question I was trying to explain, and it is a relief to see it is in fact a recognized issue, with solutions. Many thanks for the link.

Comment: mus:12345 is an IRI. The fact that it happens to be a resolvable URL which contains assertions about an object (i.e., the vase) is not part of RDF or OWL semantics, it's a convention. What RDF is saying is, this individual is 25 cm tall - dereferencing from IRI to actual vase with a physical height is outside the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RDF, each thing should get its own IRI. A good practice is to use HTTP(S) IRIs for this.

The vase (the physical object) would be one thing. A webpage that describes this vase would be another thing (an information resource).

It’s important to make sure that no webpage exists under the HTTP(S) IRI which should represent a thing which is ***not*** an information resource (e.g., a vase).

If you don’t want to publish a webpage that describes a non-information-resource thing, you don’t have to do anything special, you just need to make sure that the server will never answer with HTTP status code `200` for (exactly) that URL.

If you do want to publish webpages, there are [two conventions](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#solutions) for this: Hash IRIs and 303 IRIs.

### Example using Hash IRI

IRI for the webpage about the vase:

```
http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345
```

IRI for the vase:

```
http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345#this
```

The fragment identifier could be anything (`this`, `it`, `vase`, …), as long as there is no `id`/`name` attribute for it in the HTML document.

### Example using 303 IRI

IRI for the webpage about the vase:

```
http://somemuseum.com/descriptions/12345
```

When requesting the URL `http://somemuseum.com/descriptions/12345`, the server responds with status code `200`.

IRI for the vase:

```
http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345
```

When requesting the URL `http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/12345`, the server responds with status code `303`, and redirects to the URL `http://somemuseum.com/descriptions/12345`.

## `rdf:type`

In addition, you can (and should) make statements about the two IRIs, and put them in relation.

The webpage could get the type [`schema:ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage). To connect the two things, you could use the [`schema:mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property.

Example using the Slash IRI way:

```
@prefix voc: <http://somemuseum.com/ontology#> .
@prefix mus: <http://somemuseum.com/artifacts/> .
@prefix mus-page: <http://somemuseum.com/descriptions/> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .

voc:Vase rdf:type owl:Class .
mus:12345 rdf:type voc:Vase .

mus-page:12345 rdf:type schema:ItemPage .

mus-page:12345 schema:mainEntity mus:12345 .
```